# embed mysql database in java application

Tags: java, mysql

I make a `java` application using `netbeans` that connect to database , but i have a problem , i want to embed `mysql` database with the executable jar file , so when i take this `jar` file and run it on any pc that doesn't have mysql server it will run with database , i thought about include the mysql-installer.exe and make a script to install the mysql server , but i can't find how to do that ,also  i read about Connector/MXJ does it work if the user run the application and he does not have mysql server , any suggestion or article about this.

Comment: You could use Derby, which is a DB written entirely in Java.  You'd just have to include the jar file and you'll have a fully-functional dbms.

Comment: have you thought about sqlite?

Comment: Is the DB for query only, or is intended to allow the user to update it?

Comment: @bdares  if i use Derby how to embed it with my application

Comment: @AndrewThompson he will update it

Comment: *"i can't use sqlite"*  Please, (please, please) don't tell us what you "can't" do without explaining ***why***!  People can give you far better help when they understand the reason behind constraints.  Note also that @juergend would not be notified of the comment unless the comment is prefixed with '@PersonName'.

Comment: If the DB is for update, it *cannot* be included in a Jar.  Jars are effectively 'read only'.

Comment: i can't use sqlite i need to use foreign keys

Comment: i will create empty tables and the user will have forms to insert delete update database , sorry

Comment: I have removed the "embedded" tag as that is for embedded systems, not for embedding a database in an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) is a pure-java DBMS.  You bundle the derby jar with your program, just as you would any other library.  This is a much cleaner way of ensuring your user has a db for your program, as you're not adding any dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Usually distributors don't include standalone databases, such as MySQL or Oracle, with their
application. If needed, they provide SQL script to build the database and make the user type in the database host, username and password and make a script to build the database. If you want to "ship" the database with your application then I would consider more lightweight databases such SQLite (singe file database).